# In Select2 appears Cannot read property 'createTextRange' of undefined

Tags: javascript, html, jquery-select2

I have a select with some data.. normal data, nothing fancy and i'm using select2 to format this data like this:

```
<select class="select2-option" id="propertySet_PropertyValues_89d25cf7-fdff-4cf9-8bd6-144e05e38d3e__Value" name="propertySet.PropertyValues[89d25cf7-fdff-4cf9-8bd6-144e05e38d3e].Value" style="width: 250px" tabindex="-1" title="waist">
<option value=""></option>
<option value="84">new born</option>
<option value="85">xs</option>
<option value="86">s</option>
<option value="87">m</option>
<option value="88">l</option>
<option value="89">xl</option>
<option value="103">3 months</option>
<option value="104">6 months</option>
<option value="105">9 months</option>
<option value="106">12 months</option>
<option value="134">xxl</option>
<option value="135">child 6</option>
<option value="136">child 8</option>
<option value="137">child 10</option>
<option value="138">child 12</option>
<option value="139">child 14</option>
</select>
```

and the javascript:

```
function loadSelect2()
{
    $('.select2-option').select2();
}
```

I'm getting the message:

> Cannot read property 'createTextRange' of undefined

when I click on the select2 combo.

Comment: I have created a fiddle, but can't reproduce.... http://jsfiddle.net/vk64ox90/1/

Answer (score 1):

Try to have no dash ( - ) in your selector.